# 500 error when adding a message item attachment to a message draft

Tags: json, curl, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-restapi

Nice, just caused a couple of 500 errors on your server, grins. Tried to add another message as an attachment to a draft.

The payload (body) was

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment"
  IsInline:     false
  ContentType:  "message\rfc822"
  Name"         "original message.eml"
  Id"           originalMessageId
}
```

Here's the whole CURL command

```
'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/AAMkAGQyZTBkZjQ1LWQ3M2QtNDk2MS04MWI4LTJhNWY1MGRmYzkyNwBGAAAAAABPZeBlIKL6TJIRMaoqmdhGBwAP_JVVr_HSRLiiYMDstTKcAAAAAAEPAAAP_JVVr_HSRLiiYMDstTKcAAADdPhwAAA=/attachments'
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3436.0 Safari/537.36' -H 'Referer: https://localhost:3443/index.html?et=' -H 'Origin: https://localhost:3443' -H 'authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJnRDU5blJpQnpmbk5BVGloOFJhZ1l5M3pyZyJ9.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.hw7Vt6fvZNtpBMuvj0oikWGBRYL0AqhmZvMhJKPMoyIjXNrG0cXgDD74XcUtkGYl4hBM1IdHObXFeCazE7o2OYqzKAdBFznpJzYA-3svg0H8NjJuP1ZiObDYfsJiTySN9r7OpecImBnqp8KYxzSiDd6EUxlK3QvdUOW57bUCcZ3rRsgq4v5i5v7rV6Lz6WG-wkz_n7mbOlBuPlnjCQ0oGvYUhSYtabG6RLgVTC4Is6r6hSy0LdmmJ3030CYWQJS3Fc5amAWtV9y-6YgZesaZoJy1au1C2LcqSIjdxdQ_CSiU1bGt8Lwom5My5v5VXun-qfr8W7l5HFU2kSYjAjsCpg'
-H 'DNT: 1' -H 'content-type: application/json' --data-binary '{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment","IsInline":false,"ContentType":"message\rfc822","Name":"original message","Id":"AAMkAGQyZTBkZjQ1LWQ3M2QtNDk2MS04MWI4LTJhNWY1MGRmYzkyNwBGAAAAAABPZeBlIKL6TJIRMaoqmdhGBwAP_JVVr_HSRLiiYMDstTKcAAAAAAEdAAAP_JVVr_HSRLiiYMDstTKcAAADdQAfAAA="}'
--compressed
```

and the 500 response is this

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
    "message": "An internal  server error occurred. The operation failed."
  }
}
```

Been reading https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_post_attachments but doesn't help much with this problem.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now. No, using ItemAttachment. Just the Id parameter was wrong. Replaced that with the "Item" parameter using original JSON of message to be attached.